# Как запарсить определенный текст на Python если нету id и class

Tags: python, парсер, веб-сайт

Всем привет.Хочу написать бота, который парсит страницу и постит результат, но появилась пробелема. На сайте колледжа расписания выглядит совсем не так как я ожидал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Допустим мне надо запарсить группу 18адс 1, но как именно выбрать его? Если в одном div хранится все расписание для всех групп.

Comment: Сложная задача, учитывая, что о номере группы на скрине ни слова:-) BeautufulSoup не поможет?

Comment: @BrainCode код текстом, а не скриншотом, таковы правила данного ресурса

Comment: @СергейШашко не думаю что в этом конкретном случае это необходимо, ведь тебе не нужно копировать код или типо того

Comment: @BrainCode, a можно ссылку на расписание?

Comment: Ссылка на расписание https://uaviak.ru/pages/raspisanie-/#pos2

С помощью BeautufulSoup, я то знаю как парсить разные элементы у которых есть свой id class, но тут его нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.post('https://uaviak.ru/pages/raspisanie-/#pos2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
ras = soup.find('div', class_="scrolling-text pos2").text.split('\n')
for ur in ras:
    if ur.find('18адс1') >=0:
        print(ur)

18адс1  3     ПредпШкабров В.В.       Преддипломная  практика         Практика
```

Comment: спасибо вам огромное!